# How to get github token using username and password

Tags: authentication, github, token, rhodes

I am developing mobile apps using rhodes. I want to access private repo of github. I am having only username and password.

How to get token of given username and password.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use oauth instead: http://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/

Comment: I have a feeling, they have changed the auth pages, they no longer seem to list the use of Autherization: basic Base64(username:password) header

Comment: +1, the whole point of OAuth is to not have to ask for a username and password in the first place. The user shouldn't trust your app with their username and password, but they can trust github with it. That's the principle of OAuth: you open a github connection page for them, they connect and github gives your app the token.

Answer (score 7):

Once you have only login and password you can use them using basic auth. First of all, check if this code shows you json data of desired repo. Username and password must be separated by a colon.

```
curl -u "user:pwd" https://api.github.com/repos/user/repo
```

If succeeded you should consider doing this request from code.

```
import urllib2
import json
from StringIO import StringIO
import base64

username = "user@example.com"
password = "naked_password"

req = urllib2.Request("https://api.github.com/repos/user/repo")
req.add_header("Authorization", "Basic " + base64.urlsafe_b64encode("%s:%s" % (username, password)))
req.add_header("Content-Type", "application/json")
req.add_header("Accept", "application/json")
res = urllib2.urlopen(req)

data = res.read()
repository = json.load(StringIO(data))
```

Answer (score 5):

Github users can create *Personal Access Tokens* at their [application settings](https://github.com/settings/applications). You can use this token as an alternative to username/password in basic http authentication to call the API or to access private repositories on the github website.

Simply use a client that supports basic http authentication. Set the username equal to the token, and the password equal to `x-oauth-basic`. For example with curl:

```
curl -u <token>:x-oauth-basic https://api.github.com/user
```

See also https://developer.github.com/v3/auth/.

Answer (score 4):

Send A POST request to `/authorizations`
With headers

`Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
Authorization: Basic base64encode(<username>:<password>)`

But remember to take Two factor Authentication in mind
https://developer.github.com/v3/auth/#working-with-two-factor-authentication

Here You will receive a token which can be used for further request

Answer (score 0):

Follow [this](http://help.github.com/set-your-user-name-email-and-github-token/) guide at help.github.com. It describes how to find your api-token (it's under "Account Settings" > "Account Admin") and configuring git so it uses the token.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to use GitHub Basic Authentication in JavaScript

```
let username = "*******";
    let password = "******";
    let auth = "Basic " + new Buffer(username + ":" + password).toString("base64");
    
    var options = {
        host: 'api.github.com',
        path: '/search/repositories?q=google%20maps%20api',
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
                'user-agent': 'node.js',
                "Authorization": auth
                 }
                 };
    var request = https.request(options, function (res) {
                  }));
```